# Why does my Pin It button "scroll/flip" when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

Refer to this page for example: http://blog.froy.com/bond-street-loft-by-axis-mundi/

Hovering over any of the Pin It buttons, whether an image or in the bottom of the post, causes the button to 'scroll/flip' instead of showing a static Pin It button image.

I can't even identify what the cause is... Does anyone have any experience with this? This occurs in Chrome and Firefox. Site is running off of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that's just the way the button was setup. If you go to [this](http://passets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_bg_en_rect_gray_20_2.png) site, you'll see that's where the button is hosted. You'll notice it looks like three different buttons. That means it's a sprite and on certain activities by the mouse, it's showing a different part of the image. Just by taking a quick look I found this

```
media="all"
a, button, input:focus, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"], textarea {
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

You'll notice in that code there are the transitions, that's part of what's making the effect happen. Also this is part of the code that is showing only a certain image, notice that background-position.

```
a.PIN_1392869101137_pin_it_button_20 {
background-repeat: none!important;
background-size: 40px 60px!important;
height: 20px!important;
margin: 0!important;
padding: 0!important;
vertical-align: baseline!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
width: 40px!important;
background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

Now on the :hover notice where the background position is.

```
a.PIN_1392869101137_pin_it_button_20:hover {
background-position: 0 0px;
}
```

That change is what is causing the effect.

Comment: Tyler, thanks for your help! Your explanation was exactly what I needed. The issue was with the transitions, which were inherited from the button styling from the rest of the theme.